# mac terminal change schemes

Tags: macos, terminal

So somehow my mac terminal is looking like this. How can I change to default? Or at least not this. Open to suggestions if anyone has some styling they much prefer.

Also, is zsh the default now?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to your macOS terminal app menu `Preferences... -> Profiles -> select your prefer profile -> click 'Default' button on the bottom`. Then restart your terminal app. That's it.
2. To find out your current shell, use command `echo $SHELL`.